# Recargar DIV en Python con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, python

tengo un problema, quiero recargar un div que dentro tiene una tabla, al recargarlo uso este código:

```
function actualiza_contenido() {
                $("#recarga_auto").load("#tabla");
                }
                setInterval("actualiza_contenido()", 10000);
```

Antes de recargar el div, la tabla se mira así:
[Imagen de la tabla antes de recargar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjbVQ.png)

Pero al momento de que se ejecuta el script que recarga el div, al parecer no está volviendo a ejecutar el script, se mira así:

[Imagen de la tabla al recargar el script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqo2K.png)

Ya busque información pero no he encontrado nada al respecto, ya probe poniendo el script dentro del codigo de la tabla y cambiando la referencia que hago al script, también intente poner después del load el archivo JS pero literalmente me abre el archivo.
Espero puedan ayudarme